# I cannot use Instant Run in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I follow the guide on http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio20preview9available to update my Android Studio to the preview version.
And then I try to use Instant Run to run something.
When I open the Run Configures, I see an warning are telling "Instant Run requires a newer version of the Gradle plugin."
And there is a red-font hyperlink "Update Project".

Then I pressed it, and Android Studio give me a message "Error updating to new Gradle version"

What should I do if you want to use the Instant Run?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Use default gradle wrapper in

Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Project-level settings

And it should work if you have the good build gradle tools.

Comment: Hey Yoto Chang, how were you able to solve it. I ran into the same issue and was successful in resolving it. Any hint please?

Comment: I think this answer is obsolete in the newer version of android studio.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by misdkversion in your app gradle.build. Open it in android studio and set it to whatever version your app should support. If you hover over the red line on the version number, it will notify you what version yours should be. Then make the changes and sync your project. That is the solution to this particular problem.